# a href tag not working due to z-index

Tags: html

I have a div with class 'header' that has the z-index value as 1. After that div, i have a div for logo in anchor tags. But the problem is i dont get any pointer cursor on 'logo'. 
If i remove the z-index of header i am able to click on it.
I have .header as follows:

```
.header{
  z-index:1;
}
```

Here's the result i am getting:

[Output i am getting...](http://jsfiddle.net/chetana/pThNz/3/)

Just take away the comments in css parts that i have given for z-index. You will be able to click the logo again.

Is there a way to get the anchor tags working with the z-index value as 1 on 'header'?

Comment: I don't think you can add z index property to anchor tag, but if you want to do this, can do this by managing z index value of element behind anchor tag.
 can check out this [link][1], also there is a possibility using an image.

[1]http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Comment: Thanks Dipak... I guess u r right....

Comment: Have added a solution as well as an alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you positioning things absolutely? If you want to make your code work you need to position your a tag relative or absolute and give it a higher z-index:

http://jsfiddle.net/pThNz/11/

```
a {position:relative; z-index:2;}
```

Otherwise you could try something like this for nicer code; stops you from getting into a z-index nightmare later down the road; and just stops empty divs being created everywhere:

http://jsfiddle.net/pThNz/10/

```
<div class="header">
  <a href="http://therepublik.ambibytes.com/" title="Home">
    <span class="leftCorners">
      <span class="rightCorners">
        <span class="text">The fuzzy Republik</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header a {margin:20px; font-size: 20px; color: black; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; }
.header a,
.header span {display:block; width:283px; height:100px;}
.leftCorners {background:url(http://therepublik.ambibytes.com/wp-content/themes/republik/imgs/left_corners.gif) left top no-repeat;}
.rightCorners {background:url(http://therepublik.ambibytes.com/wp-content/themes/republik/imgs/right_corners.gif) right top no-repeat;}
.header .text {padding-top:45px; height:50px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Pete... But my requirement is that the text in logo should get behind the background of the div 'header'. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want the text (and corners?) behind the header but the link on top?

Comment: yeah... and i cannot put the logo in header section as it needs to be fixed and the logo is not fixed. Thats the reason its getting messed up...

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete.. its the same thing i want... :)

Answer (score 4):

Just add pointer-events:none to the parent that's blocking the link from clicking (so to the header).

Here's your code updated:
https://jsfiddle.net/pThNz/31/

```
.header {
    pointer-events:none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

z-index does not affect elements that are not position:absolute, relative or static

```
.header{
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}
```